# Sonar-runner.bat shows error when build called provide compiled classes

Tags: java, sonarqube, command-line-interface, sonar-runner

I am trying to run sonar-runner.bat from my java project location. When it build

> ERROR: Caused by: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property

and says BUILD FAILURE.

[image]

Comment: Always add your errors etc as text, and if you for some reason need to use picture, at least don't use one that has 75% of just blank space in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found. After I put sonar.java.binaries=target/classes, It worked.
I didn't specify the class location.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project's `target` directory contains compiled classes before running Sonar analysis. You need to run the following before running Sonar analyzer:

```
mvn clean install
```